# OutOfMemoryException while creating BitMap from Listview

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, out-of-memory, screenshot

my App throws an OutOfMemoryException while creating a BitMap from a Listview. This error is new, but didn't do any changes in the method.

It would be nice if anyone had an idea about this issue. Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:977)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:948)
  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap (Bitmap.java:915)
  at com.beerapp.givemebeerfree.utils.Helper.getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap (Helper.java:300)
  at com.beerapp.givemebeerfree.fragments.ListViewFragment$4.onClick (ListViewFragment.java:196)
  at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage (AlertController.java:162)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

And here is the method:

```
    public static Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap(SearchableAdapter adapter, ListView listview, int singleOffer){
    Bitmap bigbitmap;
    try{
        int itemscount       = adapter.getCount();
        int allitemsheight   = 0;
        List<Bitmap> bmps    = new ArrayList<>();
        // If screenshot from single offer, than the item with the shop info has to be added too
        OfferItem singleOfferItem = adapter.getItem(singleOffer);
        OfferItem item;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {
            item = adapter.getItem(i);
            if (((singleOffer == 0) || (i == singleOffer)) ||
                    ((singleOffer != 0) && (item.getShopID() == singleOfferItem.getShopID()) && item.getShopLogoID() != 0)){
                View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
                childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

                childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
                childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                childView.destroyDrawingCache();
                childView.buildDrawingCache();
                bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache(true));
                allitemsheight += childView.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
        }
        bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bigcanvas    = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int iHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
            bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
            iHeight+=bmp.getHeight();

            bmp.recycle();
            bmp=null;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

            View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);
            childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

            childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
            childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            childView.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        bigbitmap = null;
    }
    return bigbitmap;
}
```

Line 300 is:

```
bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is counter to the entire idea of using a ListView.  The point of a listView is that you DONT ever get views for all children-  you only create (and measure, and draw) children that are actually on screen.  The reason to do this is to save the massive amounts of memory a large list takes.

Basically if you ever call getView directly-  you're doing it wrong.  If you ever call getView in a loop-  you're not only doing it wrong, but you're counteracting the listview and doing it worse than if you had just made a giant view to begin with.

In addition-  if your list is large enough to take up more than a full screen, it will be HUGE.  A bitmap takes 4*width*height bytes of memory (plus some overhead).  If you have 2 screens long on a modern density device, you can be easily taking up 10s or 100s of megs.  You just don't have that much memory.

This code will never work, and can never work if the size is more than a trivial amount.  I'd start by questioning why you think you need a bitmap of every item in the view (instead of just what's on screen), as that's unlikely to be what you actually want, or achievable at all.

Comment: The picture has just 3mb.There are no more than 40 items in the Listview. The app has the function to share the whole listview. I dont had this error and nobody else from my friends, so i could not reproduce. Is there any other way or idea for doing this better?

Comment: First off-  there's no way a picture has just 3 mb.  It takes 4*width*height bytes.  Maybe it was 3 MB compressed, but Bitmap objects are not compressed.  Secondly-  40 items is way, way, way too many.  That's going to be at least 5 screens.  On a Galaxy S8, that would be  2960x1440x5x4, or about 90MB.  If you're doing nothing else at all that might crash the stack, add in the rest of your code and its almost certain to go OOM.  This is basically just not something you should ever do.